# Selecting records not found in other list of records

Tags: ponyorm

### Scenario

Players take part in events. They should provide information if they're going to attend an event or not.

### Problem to be solved

I want to select players that haven't provided information, if they plan to attend specific event.

### Your goal

As being a beginner in the technologies used, I would appreciate your validation and recommendation for improvement of the solution suggested by me below.

### Solution

**Technologies:** python, postgreSQL, and Pony ORM

**Entity model in Pony ORM:**

```
class Event(db.Entity):
    _table_ = "event"
    start = Required(date)
    players = Set("Attendance")


class Player(db.Entity):
    _table_ = "player"
    first_name = Optional(str)
    last_name = Required(str)
    phone_number = Required(str)
    email = Required(str)
    events = Set("Attendance")


class Attendance(db.Entity):
    _table_ = "attendance"
    event = Required(Event)
    player = Required(Player)
    status = Required(bool)
    PrimaryKey(event, player)
```

**Idea:**

1. Get list of players that provided the information if they attend the event
2. Get list of players that are not in list created in 1.

**Current implementation of the idea:**

```
players = select(p for p in Player if p not in select(p for p in Player
                 for a in Attendance if p == a.player and a.event == next_event))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to refactor your query to make it more simple. At first, we can replace explicit join of `Player` and `Attendance` inside the inner query to implicit join via attribute access:

```py
select(p for p in Player if p not in select(p for p in Player
       for attendance in p.events if attendance.event == next_event))
```

To simplify query further we can use [attribute lifting](https://docs.ponyorm.com/working_with_relationships.html#attribute-lifting) by writing expression `p.events.event`:

```py
select(p for p in Player if p not in select(
       p for p in Player if next_event in p.events.event))
```

`p.events` expression returns a set of `Attendance` records. In Pony when you have a set instance this set has all attributes of its items, and when you access such attribute you will get a set of all values of corresponding items attribute. The value of expression `p.events.event` will be the set of all `Event` objects linked with particular player.

The next step to simplify the query is to replace generators to lambdas. This way the query looks a bit shorter:

```py
Player.select(lambda p: p not in Player.select(
    lambda p: next_event in p.events.event))
```

But the biggest simplification can be achieved if we realize that the inner query is unnecessary and rewrite query as:

```py
Player.select(lambda p: next_event not in p.events.event)
```

I think this is the most concise way to write this query using PonyORM

Comment: Given the previously mentioned structure, how would you ask for all players attending next event. Let's say the next event  was already retrieve and is stored in the `next_event` variable. My idea was `pny.select(p.last_name for p in next_event.atts.player if next_event.atts.status is True)` but this throws an error. The workaround that works for me is `pny.select(a.player.last_name for a in Attendance if a.event == next_event and a.status is True)`

Comment: I think that your current query is the most compact (you can replace `a.status is True` to just `a.status`). In the future we should add support of more compact syntax:
`select(a.player.last_name for a in next_events.atts if a.status)` or even
`list(next_events.atts(lambda a: a.status).player.name)`